# Generic build script using Fake

Tags: f#

I have something like a generic build script for a group of projects. I am using Fake but my F# skills are pretty bad. Would you please take a look and point where I can improve it?

**ORIGINAL**

```
#I @"./bin/tools/FAKE/tools/"
#r @"./bin/tools/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open Fake
open Fake.Git
open Fake.FSharpFormatting
open Fake.AssemblyInfoFile
open Fake.ReleaseNotesHelper

type System.String with member x.contains (comp:System.StringComparison) str = x.IndexOf(str,comp) >= 0

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  BEGIN EDIT

let appName = getBuildParamOrDefault "appName" ""
let appType = getBuildParamOrDefault "appType" ""
let appSummary = getBuildParamOrDefault "appSummary" ""
let appDescription = getBuildParamOrDefault "appDescription" ""
let appAuthors = ["YourNameHere";]

//  END EDIT
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let buildDir  = @"./bin/Release" @@ appName
let releaseNotes = @"./src/" @@ appName @@ @"RELEASE_NOTES.md"
let release = LoadReleaseNotes releaseNotes

let nuget = environVar "NUGET"
let nugetOutDir = "./bin/nuget" @@ appName

Target "Clean" (fun _ -> CleanDirs [buildDir; nugetOutDir;])

Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ ->
  let packagesDir = @"./src/packages"
  !! "./**/packages.config"
  |> Seq.iter (RestorePackage (fun p ->
      { p with
          ToolPath = nuget
          OutputPath = packagesDir }))
)

Target "Build" (fun _ ->
  let appProjectFile = match appType with
                              | t when t = "msi" -> @"./src/" @@ appName + ".sln"
                              | _ -> @"./src/" @@ appName @@ appName + ".csproj"

  !! appProjectFile
      |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
      |> Log "Build-Output: "
)

Target "CreateNuGet" (fun _ ->
  let packages = [appName, appType]
  for appName,appType in packages do

      let nugetOutArtifactsDir = nugetOutDir @@ "Artifacts"
      CleanDir nugetOutArtifactsDir

      //  Exclude libraries which are part of the packages.config file only when nuget package is created.
      let nugetPackagesFile = "./src/" @@ appName @@ "packages.config"
      let nugetDependenciesFlat =
        match fileExists nugetPackagesFile with
        | t when t = true -> getDependencies nugetPackagesFile |> List.unzip |> fun(A,B) -> A
        | _ -> ["CodeContracts"]

      let excludePaths (pathsToExclude : string list) (path: string) = pathsToExclude |> List.exists (path.contains StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)|> not
      let exclude = excludePaths (nugetDependenciesFlat @ ["CodeContracts"])

      //  Copy the build artifacts to the nuget pick dir
      match appType with
      | t when t = "web" -> CopyDir nugetOutArtifactsDir (buildDir @@ "_PublishedWebsites" @@ appName) allFiles
      | t when t = "nuget" -> CopyDir nugetOutDir buildDir exclude
      | _ -> CopyDir nugetOutArtifactsDir buildDir allFiles

      //  Copy the deployment files if any to the nuget pick dir.
      let depl = @".\src\" @@ appName @@ @".\deployment\"
      if TestDir depl then XCopy depl nugetOutDir


      let nuspecFile = appName + ".nuspec"
      let nugetAccessKey =
          match appType with
          | t when t = "nuget" -> getBuildParamOrDefault "nugetkey" ""
          | _ ->  ""
      let nugetDoPublish = nugetAccessKey.Equals "" |> not
      let nugetPublishUrl = getBuildParamOrDefault "nugetserver" "https://nuget.org"

      //  Create/Publish the nuget package
      NuGet (fun app ->
          {app with
              NoPackageAnalysis = true
              Authors = appAuthors
              Project = appName
              Description = appDescription
              Version = release.NugetVersion
              Summary = appSummary
              ReleaseNotes = release.Notes |> toLines
              AccessKey = nugetAccessKey
              Publish = nugetDoPublish
              PublishUrl = nugetPublishUrl
              ToolPath = nuget
              OutputPath = nugetOutDir
              WorkingDir = nugetOutDir
          }) nuspecFile
)

"Clean"
    ==> "RestorePackages"
    ==> "Build"
    ==> "CreateNuGet"

RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "Build"
```

**IMPROVED**

```
#I @"./bin/tools/FAKE/tools/"
#r @"./bin/tools/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open Fake
open Fake.Git
open Fake.FSharpFormatting
open Fake.AssemblyInfoFile
open Fake.ReleaseNotesHelper

type System.String with member x.contains (comp:System.StringComparison) str = x.IndexOf(str,comp) >= 0

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  BEGIN EDIT

let appName = getBuildParamOrDefault "appName" ""
let appType = getBuildParamOrDefault "appType" ""
let appSummary = getBuildParamOrDefault "appSummary" ""
let appDescription = getBuildParamOrDefault "appDescription" ""
let appAuthors = ["YourNameHere";]

//  END EDIT
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let buildDir  = @"./bin/Release" @@ appName
let releaseNotes = @"./src/" @@ appName @@ @"RELEASE_NOTES.md"
let release = LoadReleaseNotes releaseNotes

let nuget = environVar "NUGET"
let nugetOutDir = "./bin/nuget" @@ appName

Target "Clean" (fun _ -> CleanDirs [buildDir; nugetOutDir;])

Target "RestorePackages" (fun _ ->
  let packagesDir = @"./src/packages"
  !! "./**/packages.config"
  |> Seq.iter (RestorePackage (fun p ->
      { p with
          ToolPath = nuget
          OutputPath = packagesDir }))
)

Target "Build" (fun _ ->
  let appProjectFile = match appType with
                        | "msi" -> @"./src/" @@ appName + ".sln"
                        | _ -> @"./src/" @@ appName @@ appName + ".csproj"

  !! appProjectFile
      |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
      |> Log "Build-Output: "
)

Target "CreateNuGet" (fun _ ->
  let packages = [appName, appType]
  for appName,appType in packages do

      let nugetOutArtifactsDir = nugetOutDir @@ "Artifacts"
      CleanDir nugetOutArtifactsDir

      //  Exclude libraries which are part of the packages.config file only when nuget package is created.
      let nugetPackagesFile = "./src/" @@ appName @@ "packages.config"
      let nugetDependenciesFlat =
        match fileExists nugetPackagesFile with
        | true -> getDependencies nugetPackagesFile |> List.unzip |> fst
        | _ -> []

      let excludePaths (pathsToExclude : string list) (path: string) = pathsToExclude |> List.exists (path.contains StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) |> not
      let exclude = excludePaths ("CodeContracts" :: nugetDependenciesFlat)

      //  Copy the build artifacts to the nuget pick dir
      match appType with
      | "web" -> CopyDir nugetOutArtifactsDir (buildDir @@ "_PublishedWebsites" @@ appName) allFiles
      | "nuget" -> CopyDir nugetOutDir buildDir exclude
      | _ -> CopyDir nugetOutArtifactsDir buildDir allFiles

      //  Copy the deployment files if any to the nuget pick dir.
      let depl = @".\src\" @@ appName @@ @".\deployment\"
      if TestDir depl then XCopy depl nugetOutDir


      let nuspecFile = appName + ".nuspec"
      let nugetAccessKey =
          match appType with
          | "nuget" -> getBuildParamOrDefault "nugetkey" ""
          | _ ->  ""
      let nugetDoPublish = nugetAccessKey.Equals "" |> not
      let nugetPublishUrl = getBuildParamOrDefault "nugetserver" "https://nuget.org"

      //  Create/Publish the nuget package
      NuGet (fun app ->
          {app with
              NoPackageAnalysis = true
              Authors = appAuthors
              Project = appName
              Description = appDescription
              Version = release.NugetVersion
              Summary = appSummary
              ReleaseNotes = release.Notes |> toLines
              AccessKey = nugetAccessKey
              Publish = nugetDoPublish
              PublishUrl = nugetPublishUrl
              ToolPath = nuget
              OutputPath = nugetOutDir
              WorkingDir = nugetOutDir
          }) nuspecFile
)

"Clean"
    ==> "RestorePackages"
    ==> "Build"
    ==> "CreateNuGet"

RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "Build"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the match expressions can be simplified. For example,

> ```
> match fileExists nugetPackagesFile with
> | t when t = true -> ...
> | _ -> ...
> ```

Can be

```
match fileExists nugetPackagesFile with
| true -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

Similarly,

> ```
>  match appType with
>  | t when t = "web" -> ...
>  | t when t = "nuget" -> ...
>  | _ -> ...
> ```

Can be

```
  match appType with
  | "web" -> ...
  | "nuget" -> ...
  | _ -> ...
```

In the first example above, `fun(A,B) -> A` can be written as `fst`.

---

It looks like `nugetDependenciesFlat` is only used by `exclude`, where you're already appending `"CodeContracts"`. So you can change the second match in `nugetDependenciesFlat` from `_ -> ["CodeContracts"]` to `_ -> []`.

While you're at it, change `nugetDependenciesFlat @ ["CodeContracts"]` to `"CodeContracts" :: nugetDependenciesFlat`. The reason being, prepending an element to a list is a constant-time operation, while appending will take time proportional to to the length of `nugetDependenciesFlat`. It won't make a noticeable difference since I assume `nugetDependenciesFlat` will be very short, but it's a good practice to get into.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about this. Would you please help me with the fst?

Comment: @mynkow Sure, so instead of `getDependencies nugetPackagesFile |> List.unzip |> fun(A,B) -> A` you can write `getDependencies nugetPackagesFile |> List.unzip |> fst`. Documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370480.aspx).

Comment: Got it. Is there something for the second element?

Comment: @mynkow Yep, it's called `snd`.

Comment: you rock. If you go to "//  Exclude libraries which are part of the..." The idea there is to have "CodeContracts" directory excluded always and if packages.config exists to exclude files described there. I do not like this piece of code especially "| _ -> ["CodeContracts"]" just to make the compile happy. Any ideas how to make it better?

Comment: @mynkow It was getting long so I addressed that in the answer.

Comment: Nice. I really appreciate you answer

Comment: @mynkow Cheers :) If a better answer comes along, please do accept that one instead. I only skimmed the code.